# Syntax error in while loop near unexpected token `in'

Tags: shell

I want to process some data and I need to narrow the area to process by reading some coordinates written in a text file,..

I have the following error:

`./script5.sh: line 59: syntax error near unexpected token`in'
./script5.sh: line 59: `while IFS="" read -r $L1Aname north south east west || [[ -n "$L1Aname north south east west" ]] in $coord; do'`

This is what I have:

```
while IFS="" read -r $L1Aname north south east west || [[ -n "$L1Aname north south east west" ]] in $coord; do
    Nlat="$north"  #name variable north
    Slat="$south"  #name variable south
    Elon="$east"  #name variable east
    Wlon="$west" #name variable west
done < "$coord";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your use of `in` keyword in the `while` loop is incorrect. Also, the variable `$L1Aname` if holds a valid variable name then it's somewhat ok. OTW this is destined to fail. Also, the [[ -n "...." ]] test will always pass so this is an infinite loop, sort of, once the `in` keyword is taken care of.

Comment: It looks like you may have converted a `for variable in $coord` loop to a `while` loop, and forgot to remove `in $coord` when you made that change. Or somehow you've merged the two loops.

Comment: Why do you read into one set of variables and then assign to another set? Why not just `read L1Aname Nlat Slat Elon Wlon`?

Comment: @RakeshSharma I don't know how to tell the script to read the 'line' in a text file, I thought `in` would work but apparently no, how can I fix this? 
`$L1Aname` hold a variable prior to this loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while-loop looks, as Barmar points out in his comment to the question, as if it was originally a for-loop that iterated over `$coord` (a variable possibly holding the whole contents of a file).

The correct while-loop may look something like

```
while read -r L1Aname north south east west; do
    Nlat="$north"
    Slat="$south"
    Elon="$east"
    Wlon="$west"
done <"$coord"
```

I have also dropped the `$` in `$L1Aname`. I'm not entirely sure this is correct though as you *could* `read $L1Aname` (this would read a value into the variable *whose name* is stored in the variable `L1Aname`). I will assume that this was unintentional though (just change `L1Aname` to `$L1Aname` below if I'm wrong).

If you need to check for non-empty values, don't test on the string `"$L1Aname north south east west"` as this is guaranteed to be non-empty. Instead, test the values of the individual variables:

```
while read -r L1Aname north south east west
    && [ -n "$north" ] && [ -n "$south" ]
    && [ -n "$east"  ] && [ -n "$west"  ]
do
    Nlat="$north"
    Slat="$south"
    Elon="$east"
    Wlon="$west"

    # use "$Nlat", "$Slat", "$Elon" and "$Wlon" here.

done <"$coord"
```

You don't need to test on `$L1Aname` as this is guaranteed to contain *something* if the `read` was able to read something.